# Accessing Code Signing Certificates on OSX in order to build an XCode provisioning utility [C# preferred]

Tags: xcode, macos, provisioning, certificate

I'm creating a utility in C# to setup provisions and build settings for an iPhone project.

The XCode project file contains these lines:

```
            CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS = ***;
            CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY = ***;
            "CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY[sdk=iphoneos*]" = "***";
            ...
            PROVISIONING_PROFILE = ***;
            "PROVISIONING_PROFILE[sdk=iphoneos*]" = "***";
```

Currently I am getting a list of provisioning profiles from ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/ and using some of their plain text values to set up the provisioning section.

I'm wondering if there is any way to access a list of installed certificates to set up the Code_Sign_Entitlements section. I don't need any encrypted data - just the names of installed certificates, and, ideally, a way to match them to the provisioning profiles.

Do they have a file location? Is there any way to access them through apple script or some similar means?

Thanks!

Matthew